# Splitting a list column into an entry per column

Tags: r, list, dplyr, nested, tidyr

I would like to split a list column element into individual columns.

For example, in the starwars dataset,

```
data("starwars")
```

I would want this list column (the entry in row 7)

```
c("Attack of the Clones", "Revenge of the Sith", "A New Hope")
```

To be broken into columns A,B,C... with the values of the movies

```
   A                          B                   C       D    ...
Attack of the Clones   Revenge of the Sith   A New Hope   NA   ...
```

I have kind of hacked together a way to do this with

```
starwars %>% separate(films, into= letters[1:7],sep = ",")
```

Which would result in an output of

```
       A                          B                   C             D     ...
c("Attack of the Clones"   "Revenge of the Sith"   "A New Hope")    NA    ...
```

But this will require some additional scrubbing, and I don't think this is general. Is there a way to do this in one swoop?

Comment: You can use `map` to loop through the list.  But, it is unclear about the `NA` you wanted

Comment: The NA would be the value for a character who appears in less than the max number (7) of movies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'films' column is a `list` of `vector`s.  If we wanted to create `data.frame` with 7 columns i.e. `max`imum `length` of the 'films' and store it as `list`, assign the `length` to maximum length from the whole column, convert it to a `data.frame`

```
library(tidyverse)
mx <- max(lengths(starwars$films))
starwars %>% 
   mutate(films = map(films, ~ `length<-`(.x, mx) %>% 
                  as.data.frame.list %>% 
                  set_names(LETTERS[seq_len(mx)]))) %>%
   unnest(films)
```

---

Or another option is `pull` the 'films' column, convert it to `tibble` within n `map`, bind with the columns of 'starwars' except the 'films'

```
starwars %>% 
    pull(films) %>% 
    map_df(~ t(.x) %>% 
               as_tibble) %>%
    bind_cols(starwars %>% 
                 select(-films), .)
```

Comment: This is almost the opposite of what I want. I would want a COLUMN called A, with the value of Attack of the Clones, a COLUMN called B with value Revenge of the Sith ... . Thank you for the quick response though!

Comment: @RayVelcoro  How is it opposite of what you wanted.

Comment: I would like to add a column to the starwars dataset called A, B, ... with the value of film that is broken out. I have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: @RayVelcoro  I updated both solutions, and hope it helps now

Comment: The later with the pull is EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: It should be noted though that this warning came up Warning message:
`as_tibble.matrix()` requires a matrix with column names or a `.name_repair` argument. Using compatibility `.name_repair`.

Comment: @RayVelcoro  Could be a different version of tibble.  Not getting that warning here though

Comment: I get a warning of factor coercing to character.  It is a type issue.  Should have started with `character`

Comment: For what it is worth--- this was also displayed with it "This warning is displayed once per session. "

Comment: @RayVelcoro  I used `packageVersion('tibble')
[1] ‘2.0.1’`